# Я не пойму в чём ошибка

Tags: discord.py

```
import discord
import requests as requests
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import requests

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*')

@bot.command()
async def kiska(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Нету кисок:3')

bot.remove_command('info')

@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="У нас есть бот поддержки в телеграме", description="@shluba_bot")
    embed.set_footer(text="Иногда бот может не ответить")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
bot.remove_command('help')


@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Список комманд")
    embed.add_field(name="*kotik", value="Показвает котика:3", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*kiska", value="Пока-что в бете", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*info", value="Обратиться в поддержку", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @bot.command()
    async def fox(ctx):
        response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/fox')  # Get-запрос
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)  # Извлекаем JSON
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff9900, title='Random Fox')  # Создание Embed'a
        embed.set_image(url=json_data['link'])  # Устанавливаем картинку Embed'a
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)  # Отправляем Embed
```

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "fox" is not found
```

Comment: В том, что вы написали функцию внутри функции, возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты команду отодвинул от начала строки,

Надо воооооть так:

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Список комманд")
    embed.add_field(name="*kotik", value="Показвает котика:3", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*kiska", value="Пока-что в бете", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="*info", value="Обратиться в поддержку", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def fox(ctx):
    response = requests.get('https://some-random-api.ml/img/fox')  # Get-запрос
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)  # Извлекаем JSON
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff9900, title='Random Fox')  # Создание Embed'a
    embed.set_image(url=json_data['link'])  # Устанавливаем картинку Embed'a
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)  # Отправляем Embed
```

И все!